# Google Spreasheet: equivalent to INDEX and MATCH using ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find the equivalent of this using `ARRAYFORMULA`, so that I can just put the formula in the first cell instead of dragging the formula down for each row (and I guess saving computational power):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('RANGE_TO_TAKE_DATA_FROM'!$A:$B,MATCH($A1,'RANGE_TO_LOOKUP'!$BH:$BH,0)),"")
```

I know that `ARRYFORMULA` doesn't support `INDEX`, so I tried using `VLOOKUP` without any luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `vlookup`:

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(A1:A, {'RANGE_TO_LOOKUP'!$BH:$BH,'RANGE_TO_TAKE_DATA_FROM'!$A:$B},{2,3},0),0))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get this error: "Wrong number of arguments to ARRAYFORMULA. Expected 1 arguments, but got 2 arguments." I removed the last parenthesis as it was mismatched..?

Comment: Oh, I've corrected the formula. I wrote it without checking, my fault

Comment: This keeps adding rows (I'm at 12000 now..) and the error says "Please add more rows"

Comment: Sure, you may limit the number of rows in your formula. Try converting `A1:A` into → `offset(A1,,,counta(A1:A))`. You won't have the problem if you paste the formula into the first row.

Comment: Thanks! Working :-)